# Quicksort or Selectionsort?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, quicksort, selection-sort

I have question about quicksort and selection sort. I have read many posts here but none of them answers my question. 
Take a look:
We have 10GB of numbers and we have to sort them. However, we have only 800mb of memory available so mergesort is out of the question. Now, because of the hugeee size of the array, bubblesort is also out of the question.
Personally, I think both sortin algorithms are great for this job, however I have to choose only one of them, the one that works better. 
Quicksort: Usually has : O(N * logN) and worst: O(N^2)
Selectionsort: usually & worst : O(N^2)
Quicksort seems better, but from my experience, I think that Selectionsort is slightly better that quick sort for huge data structures. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: Tested it. Quicksort is much better than Selectionsort. I was wrong. the right choise was Quicksort and it worked perfectly with an alteration to the available memory (moved to 1 GB) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`selection sort is slightly better than quicksort for huge data structures`! Where did you get this from? The algorithm takes quadratic time so it's obviously much worse than quicksort. Actually, how are you going to fit 10GB in RAM, you can't use any algorithm on your array if it's not in RAM. You need an external sorting algorithm or you might store the data in a DB and let the DB engine sort it for you.

Comment: Is that just theory? Because I just tested it and found for a randomly generated list/array of random generated values, selection sort is on average 10x slower than quick sort... Maybe you're confusing selection sort with merge sort?

Answer (score 2):

Quick sort is better for such huge data than selection sort. Selection sort might perform better in cases where the test data has a larger sets of sorted data within. But that doesn't in anyway make it better than quick sort. Your main problem in your case is on how to proceed with sorting such huge data as it cannot be held in memory and executed

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort should be used for this situation due to it being the current fastest sorting algorithm. Because selection sort looks through every term to find the smallest number and putting it at the front, it will take much longer (especially if there is a huge data structure as mentioned), even with a limited amount of memory.